# PHP-PEAR require_once('DB.php');

Tags: php, pear

I've a problem with PEAR (PHP). This is the error:

```
Warning: require_once(DB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /WWW/xxx.php on line 2
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'DB.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /WWW/xxx.php on line 2
```

I've already installed PEAR (version 1.9.0)
In my PHP file the first two lines are these:

```
1- <?php
2- require_once('DB.php');
```

Where's the problem?
Thank you all!

Comment: Have you checked if the file DB.php exists in the include path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the module:

```
pear install DB
```

Although [this page](http://pear.php.net/package/DB) gives a warning about this package being superseded (*not* deprecated) by [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2).

Comment: If you get `XML Extension not found` message, you first need to install php-xml package with `sudo apt-get install php-xml` (assuming Debian/Ubuntu).

Answer (score 3):

You can also install module without using pear:

With *Fedora/CentOS*:

- yum install php-pear-DB

With *Debian/Ubuntu*:

- apt-get install php-db

--
Dario